# Regex for matching <br /> followed by a new line and a digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to split a paragraph with javascript if inside of the paragraph I have `<br />` followed by newline and by a digit.

Here is the example of the paragraph:

```
aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaa <br />
1   bbbb bbbbb bbbbb bbbb bbb <br />
2   cccc ccccc ccccc cccc ccc <br />
*   dddd ddddd ddddd dddd ddd <br />
```

And I would like to have an array with 3 elements inside:

```
1.  aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaa <br />
2.  1   bbbb bbbbb bbbbb bbbb bbb <br />
3.  2   cccc ccccc ccccc cccc ccc <br />
    *   dddd ddddd ddddd dddd ddd <br />
```

I have tried this:

```
<br \/>\d
```

But this not worked because of the newline I guess.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What is `\d`? Line feeds are `\n`

Comment: `\d` is digit (numeric value)

Comment: If the markup is from an element's `innerHTML` property then it will not have `<br />` but `<BR>` and new lines will be removed, regardless of what is in the markup because innerHTML is not the markup, it is valid HTML. If the markup is from some other source, then it should be literal text so you can split on whatever character pattern you like.

Comment: Two very good resources for learning REGEX: http://www.rubular.com/ and http://www.regexone.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the string is stored in a variable called `str`, the following should work:

```
str.split(/<br \/>$[\s\S]^(?=\d+)/m)
```

I have used:

- Multi-line mode (`/m`), to allow the $ to match the end of one line, and the ^ to match the start of the next.
- A javascript regex trick to match any character, including new lines: `[\s\S]`, as detailed [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).
- A [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead), to make sure the thing following the new line is a digit: `(?=\d+)`. It is not included in the match, though, so the digits are not removed from the string.

**EDIT:** This will remove the `<br />`s from all but the last element in the list. Since I cannot think of a better way right now, you could just re-add them using something like:

```
var parts = str.split(/<br \/>$[\s\S]^(?=\d+)/m);
var final = [];
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
    final.push(parts[i] + '<br />');
}
final.push(parts[parts.length - 1]);
```

Not ideal, but seems to work for me.

Comment: This also removes the `<br />` from the string. And you don't need `[\s\S]` - newlines match `\s`.

Comment: @Tim Good point. I can't seem to figure out a way to leave the `<br />`s in there. Oh well.

Comment: 2GregL, thank you for your answer but this is not working for me, it is not matching anything. Please, try to check here http://regexr.com?31kao

Comment: @Ana You cannot seem to do `.split()` with that tool, however cool it is (the reason it didn't match anything was that you didn't have *multiline* ticked). I have updated my answer to show you how you can just add the `<br />`s back in manually.

Comment: Great, it works now, thank you very much. PS: In fact, I dont need to keep <br /> so there is not a problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

### You should try http://txt2re.com/ for regular expressions. It is very good and will help you generate regular expressions very much.

```
("aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaa <br />\r\n\
1   bbbbbbbbbbb <br />\r\n\
2   cccc ccccc ccccc cccc ccc <br />\r\n\
3   dddd ddddd ddddd dddd ddd <br />")
    .split(/\s*([\d|\*]+.+<br[^>]*>)[\r|\n|\r\n]\s*/gmi) 
                                      // criteria filtering
    .join('\r\n')                     // removing the last empty element (2nd) after split
    .replace(/\r\n\r\n/gmi,'\r\n')    // remove double line breaks
    .split(/\r\n/);                   // split again
```

Comment: This will remove the numbers from the output, unfortunately.

Comment: @GregL just wrap in parenthesis everything you don't want to be removed. I've updated.

Comment: Thank you @GRIGORE-TURBODIESEL, your example works but this will remove the digit and I need the digit. Could you please give me an example of how to keep the digit

Comment: Thanks again @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL, but I have a new problem now: the string is splitted in 7 arrays: 0. "aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaa <br />" ; 1. "1" ; 2. "bbbb bbbbb bbbbb bbbb bbb <br />"  etc.

Comment: @Ana try it now. If you want to take out the `<br />`s move `)` before it (you can see right now it includes the `<br[^>]*>` part)

Comment: This will not correctly combine a line starting with `*` with the previous line, unfortunately. Good try, though!

Comment: @GregL oh I though star means any digit. I updated to include stars.

Comment: Close, but the result of running your latest edit with a star on the last line gives 4 elements in the array, not 3 as requested. See http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/8AFMJ/ for an example.